# unwrap in beautiful soup not removing all tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following code provides the piece of HTML code as seen below it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# open webpage
url = "https://www.google.com/finance?cid=12377955"
pageSource = urlopen(url).read()

# parse HTML into Beautiful Soup
savSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, "html.parser")

# extract data from soup
divData = savSoup.find_all("span", class_= "pr")

print(divData)
---
```

This returns in the command line:

```
---
[<span class="pr">
<span id="ref_12377955_1">2.13</span>
</span>]
```

I am after the 2.13 - I have followed a number of answers from here, but the closest I have got is the removal of the span class tag only - I can't seem to shift the id.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a single element, use `.find()` instead of `.find_all()` and [`.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get the element's text:

```
value = savSoup.find("span", class_= "pr").get_text(strip=True)
```

`strip=True` here would help to remove the extra newlines and spaces around the text.

Then, you can further convert it to a float using `float(value)`.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Man thanks - I will enjoy seeing how much this solution can do!